# Unir video(con sonido) y audio externo

Tags: java, android

Necesito unir a un archivo `mp4` (con audio incluido, grabado de la cámara), una canción en `mp3`(o `aac`, o el formato que sea, me es indiferente en este caso). La única condición es que no puedo usar `FFMPEG`.
Encontré por internet el MP4Parser que podría asemejarse a lo que busco pero, no ha habido forma de hacerlo funcionar:

```
String f1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/small.mp4";
String f2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/musica_1.aac";
MovieCreator.build(f1);
MovieCreator.build(f2);
```

El error que siempre me da es:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.coremedia.iso.boxes.MovieBox.getBoxes(java.lang.Class)' on a null
```

Seguramente alguien me dirá que compruebe que `f1` y `f2` no son nulos: no, no lo son, es más, este problema solo me surge cuando intento unir el archivo que he grabado; si uso un `mp4` bajado de internet no me lo une pero al menos no me da ese error. El error surge a raíz de que intenta obtener         `List<TrackBox> trackBoxes = isoFile.getMovieBox().getBoxes(TrackBox.class);`
 Necesito poder hacer lo mismo para el archivo grabado con el telefono.
A continuación indico la configuración para grabar el vídeo desde el teléfono:

```
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity());
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(30);
     mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/small.mp4");
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

¿alguien conoce una forma de unir un mp4 con un aac (mp3 o lo que sea)?

Comment: "Unir" te refieres a crear un único archivo de audio o "unir" puede ser reproducir ambos al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Seria muy útil que definieras "unir"

Comment: Perdón, con unir me refiero a juntar el audio externo con el mp4, que todo sea un mismo archivo

Answer (score 1):

¿Ya intentaste con los ejemplos de la documentación?
Primero guardar el video desde la cámara en un archivo, ya que lo tienes en el archivo ahora si "unirlos".

```
H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("video.h264"));
AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("audio.aac"));

Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.addTrack(h264Track);
movie.addTrack(aacTrack);

Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.mp4")).getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fc.close();
```

https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si, ya probé, el problema es que mi archivo es MP4 y al intentar hacer la operación `new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("video.h264"));` nunca llega a terminar, la operación se queda ahí bloqueada. Si que la codificación es H264. También he de remarcar que no entiendo muy bien la diferencia entre H264 y MP4, por tanto igual estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que confundes el formato del archivo con la codificación del mismo.

Ejemplo un archivo de word tiene codificación ISO-8859-1 pero su formato es .docx

Comment: Prueba saber la codificación del archivo con MediaInfo o algún programa similar y ya ver si esa biblioteca soporta ese tipo de codificación.